# Cannot get makefile to work

Tags: makefile

I'm doing the [LazyFoo game tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/cli/index.php).

I've downloaded the SDL library as instructed.  I'm following along with the Linux OS instructions using the command line directions.

I created a directory called 'FooPoo' and placed the source code for the first lesson into this directory.

I then did as he says to do here:

> Save this Makefile code to a file named "Makefile" (case sensitive
>   with no file extension) or you can use the one I premade **here**. 
>   Open a command line in the directory with the source files and run the
>   command **make all**. Make will search for a file named "Makefile" in
>   the directory Make was called in and run the Makefile that will
>   compile your code.

by creating a folder called Makefile and pasting his premade code into it.

I then went to the FooPoo directory that the source code was located in and entered `make all` as told.  This is what the command line fed back to me:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Can you include the contents of Makefile  and a directory listing of the project in your post? Please paste what's on your system as opposed to quoting the tutorial.

Comment: Did you create a _folder_ called `Makefile`?